# Can I use hyphens after two separate words, using "and" as a connector?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm writing a Cover Letter and I'm including the following sentence:

"Furthermore, I have a passion for dealing with- and meeting- new people."

I recall an English professor suggesting something like this because, here, the "with" and the "meeting" both relate directly to "new people."

Is this correct? Or should I just stick with commas and get on with my life (as below)?

"Furthermore, I have a passion for dealing with, and meeting, new people." <-- seems weird.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hyphens here definitely look weird, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't use hyphens here. What you're looking for is the em dash (—). The em dash is much longer in length than the hyphen and is used for things like creating nonessential clauses like you have in your sentence.

The correct punctuation is this: *Furthermore, I have a passion for dealing with—and meeting—new people.* You can put spaces around each em dash if that's your style; it's not a rule written in stone.

However, using commas is also a correct way to punctuate this. In fact, it's definitely better than using em dashes because em dashes signify larger emphasis or longer pauses.